# Ись. Значение слова.

Tags: словарь

Что означает слово "ись"? И есть ли вообще такое или оно авторское?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ись* - это **есть** в том или ином значении. Вместо *то есть* - *то ись*. Или так :

> Владимир Личутин. Любостай (1987)
> ― Нас у матки восьмеро было, мал маля, ― сказал он. ― **Ись хотим.** Матка малых-то с собой в поле таскала.
>
> Виктор Астафьев. Царь-рыба (1974)
> Ребенок-то нисе не понимат, **ему дай ись**, и все.
>
> Владимир Личутин. Вдова Нюра (1973)
> ― Заботы о хлебе насущном гнетут, сынушка… ― Тогда бы хорошо **долго не ись.** Раз поел, а потом бы играй все да играй.
>
> Б. В. Шергин. Волшебное кольцо (1930-1960)
> Кошка с собакой рыбьи внутренности **стали ись** да свое кольцо и нашли…

Просторечных произношений в литературе огромное количество, без этого писателям не обойтись никак. Понять их смысл из контекста довольно легко, особенно когда сам в жизни сталкивался с малограмотной/простодушной народной речью.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, укороченное от команды "Иси!" -"сюда!" (охотн.)
Ср. Одевайся, бери свое ружье! Эй, Флерка, иси! — крикнул он собаке.
Ант. П. Чехов. В сумерках. Беспокойный.
Ср. Ну прощай, Лука! Спасибо на добром слове. Дамка, иси!
А.П. Чехов. Свирель.
(Это галлицизм.  Ici! (фр.) — сюда.)

Comment: Думаю, здесь нужно упомянуть контекст: 
......
Прочно, порядком было там всё уставлено на своих местах: кура, она для того, чтобы "ись", собачья шкура -- "разоставок в хозяйстве". 
.....

Кстати, слово "разоставок" мне тоже не понятно.

Comment: "разоставок в хозяйстве" - подспорье. Контекст, конечно, всегда нужно давать.